# 404 Error on all Web Apps I try to run

Tags: jboss7.x, glassfish-4.1

Over the course of the week I have had to run a couple of applications in a couple of containers. Initially I tried to run a basic REST service app on glassfish. Whenever I tried to make a call I would get a 404 error. I spent about 2 days trying to solve this and couldn't even reach a basic Hello World index.html - I would just get 404.

Next I started following a tutorial for a REST service on JBoss. It's very simple - an interface, a class that implements it, and a web.xml. I run it on JBoss and again, 404.

I've checked the URLs, fiddled around with different options and combos and whatever else I could find or think of. I'm beginning to wonder if it could be some external issue. Any ideas?

Comment: This question isn't a great format right now. There could well be different issues with the different tutorials you're using and how you deploy them to two different app servers. Could you edit your question to have more details about just one instance of this problem? Please include any details of the context path set in your application and any context path you might set when you deploy. It would probably also help to link to the tutorial and any differences between it and your steps.

Comment: Thanks Mike, as it turns out I was making the same mistake across everything - the URL was wrong because it needed to include the maven-generated package name. Found that out by accident

Comment: ah, yes, including the version number? You can generally override that in your web.xml or when you deploy the application to JBoss or GlassFish. An easier way is to just rename the WAR to what you want the context path to be and put it in the `autodeploy` folder in GlassFish or the `deployments` folder in JBoss. They should just use the filename if there's nothing specified in the web.xml.

Comment: Wow I wish I had this information ages ago. Thanks Mike!